# Python MySQLdb substituting strings into mysql conn

Tags: python

I have a connection line as below and I want to substitute in variables, but cannot get it to work:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="database")
```

I change this to use a variable:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="%s", passwd="password", db="database") % "root"
```

Error: `mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '%s'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")`

So, it is not substituting and tries to run the query with `%s`. I also tried with a .format (instead of %s) and got the same issue.

To get around this, I was going to substitute the line beforehand and then add in the connection line as one argument, however even a basic version of this doesn't work for me. Here is a trial run, but it fails even without any substituation:

```
variable = '''MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="database")''' 
db = MySQLdb.connect(variable)
```

This results in mysql trying to pass the entire variable as the first argument (the host): `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, 'Unknown MySQL server host \'host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="database"\' (2)')`

Comment: While Daniel's answer is definitely correct and to be preferred, the actual mistake you made here is this: You're dealing with 4 strings here (used as keyword arguments). You would need to apply the substitution to the individual string(s) for your approach to work, like this: `MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="%s" % "root", passwd="password", db="database-%s" % n)`

Comment: @LukasGraf thanks for the clarification. I had considered that but didn't try it since it looked like something that would throw an error fi I had `% "root"` in the middle of the command. Guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're over thinking this. This is a standard function call, and has nothing at all that is specific to MySQLdb. As with any call, if you want to use a variable, you just do so:

```
user = 'root'
MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user=user, passwd="password", db="database")
```